# Store JSON file data in localStorage with jQuery/Ajax

Tags: jquery, mysql, json, ajax, foreach

I have this JSON file:

```
[{
    "shop_name": "shop1",
    "queue_current_number": "1"
}, {
    "shop_name": "shop2",
    "queue_current_number": "2"
}, {
    "shop_name": "shop3",
    "queue_current_number": "3"
}, {
    "shop_name": "shop4",
    "queue_current_number": "4"
}]
```

I'm using ajax/jQuery for get results from JSON file, so save into local Storage:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "myPage.php",
    dataType: 'html',     
    success: function(data) { 
        data = JSON.parse(data); 
        data.forEach(function(dataItem){
            var queue_current_number = dataItem.queue_current_number;
            localStorage.setItem("queue_current_number", ""+queue_current_number+"");
        });
    }
});
```

localStorage result should be > 1234

instead my result is > 1

what is my mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not your issue directly, but `dataType: 'html'` makes no sense. If the server is returning JSON then tell jQuery that by setting `dataType: "json"`. Then `data` will be JSON from the start - jQuery will parse it for you and you can remove the line `data = JSON.parse(data);`. I don't know why you would tell jQuery to expect HTML when you know it's going to be JSON? The meaning of all the options in $.ajax is clearly documented: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ For "dataType" it says "The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.".

Comment: Anyway I think the problem with the code is that you keep overwriting `queue_current_number` when you seem to want to add to it instead. Try             var queue_current_number = ""; ;
`data.forEach(function(dataItem){
  queue_current_number += dataItem.queue_current_number; });
            localStorage.setItem("queue_current_number", ""+queue_current_number+"");` This should concatenate all the values together and store it once.

Comment: I change dataType "html" with dataType "json" and removed data = JSON.parse(data); Then updated with your code and work! thank you!

Comment: that's great. I posted it as the full answer, if you would like to mark it accepted - thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the code is that you keep overwriting queue_current_number when you seem to want to add to it instead. Try

```
var queue_current_number = ""; 
data.forEach(function(dataItem){ 
  queue_current_number += dataItem.queue_current_number; 
});   
localStorage.setItem("queue_current_number", ""+queue_current_number+"");
```

This will concatenate all the values together into a single string and store it once, instead of keep over-writing the value.